# dplyr n_distinct() in filter takes forever where as base length(unique()) works like charm

Tags: r, performance, dplyr

I have a data frame such as this:

```
structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 
19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 
32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 
45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 
52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 
58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 
65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 
71L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 
78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 
84L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 
91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 
97L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 100L), y = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("one", "two"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), .Names = c("x", "y"))
```

I am trying to filter groups of `x` that have two distinct `y` values using:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(n_distinct(y) > 1)
```

On a large data set, this almost never finishes.

Changing to this works reasonably fast for the full data set:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(length(unique(y)) > 1)
```

Any idea why n_distinct() is super slow to never finishing?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/977)